# Como exibir parte de um texto armazenado em uma coluna TEXT?

Tags: php, mysql

Minha tabela possui um campo `TEXT` onde insiro texto com parágrafos que são lidos através da função `nl2br` do PHP.

Faço print de cada coluna da tabela através de `mysql_fetch_array` e tudo é exibido corretamente:

```
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entrada` WHERE `id_destino` =".$_GET['id']);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
echo nl2br($row2['historia']);
```

Como disse anteriormente, meu texto possui vários parágrafos, mas gostaria de saber como faço para exibir apenas uma parte de tal texto ou um parágrafo apenas?

Não estou conseguindo / sabendo como aplicar essa exceção. Seria no `$row2`, `echo`, ou em nenhum dos dois? Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: vc quer exibir por exemplo os 200 primeiro caracteres do texto ou é exibir somente um paragrafo aleatorio? Cada paragrafo é separado um por um `<br> `. Se possivel coloque um texto curto de exemplo.

Comment: leia o link: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php e faça assim que acredito que resolva:

`$itens = explode("<br />", nl2br($row2['historia']));`
`echo $itens[0];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seguem vários exemplos para ilustrar as possibilidades. Basta entender a lógica básica, e recombinar de acordo com o resultado desejado!

### Soluções com PHP:

```
<?php
   $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entrada` WHERE `id_destino` =".$_GET['id']);
   $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);

   $historia = $row2['historia'];

   // Mostrar os primeiros 300 caracteres:
   echo nl2br(
      substr($historia, 0, 300)
   );

   // Mostrar o primeiro parágrafo com PHP 5.3 ou maior:
   echo nl2br(
      strstr($historia, chr(10), true);
   );

   // Mostrar o primeiro parágrafo:
   echo nl2br(
      substr($historia, 0, strpos($historia, chr(10) ) - 1);
   );

   // Mostrar o primeiro parágrafo, ou o próximo,
   // se este tiver menos  de 100 caracteres:
   echo nl2br(
      substr($historia, 0, strpos($historia, chr(10), 100 ) - 1);
   );

   // Mostrar cerca de 300 caracteres, mas sem quebrar palavras:
   echo nl2br(
      substr($historia, 0, strpos($historia, ' ', 300 ) - 1);
   );

?>
```

Obs: caso vá utilizar textos em UTF-8, dê preferências às funções *multibyte* `mb_substr` e `mb_strpos`

### Soluções com SQL:

```
$id = 0 + $_GET['id']; // SEU SCRIPT ORIGINAL É PORTA PARA SQL INJECTION! 
                       // USE mysqli_ E BINDING NO LUGAR DE mysql_

//Primeiros 200 caracteres:
$query = "SELECT LEFT(`historia`,200) FROM `entrada` WHERE `id_destino` = $id"

//Primeiro paragrafo:
$query = "SELECT LEFT(`historia`,INSTR(`historia`,CHAR(10))-1) FROM `entrada` WHERE `id_destino` = $id"

//Cerca de 200 caracteres, quebrando entre palavras :
$query = "SELECT LEFT( `historia`, 199 + INSTR( SUBSTR( `historia`, 200 ),' ' ) ) FROM `entrada` WHERE `id_destino` = $id"

$res2 = mysql_query($query);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
echo nl2br($row2['historia']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função substr() da seguinte maneira:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Fonte: [Função substr (php.net)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

Ficaria assim para mostrar os 30 primeiros caracteres:

```
echo substr(nl2br($row2['historia']), 0, 30);
```

ou

```
<?php
function textLimit($string, $length, $replacer = '...'){
  if(strlen($string) > $length)
  return (preg_match('/^(.*)\W.*$/', substr($string, 0, $length+1), $matches) ? $matches[1] : substr($string, 0, $length)) . $replacer;
  return $string;
}

echo textLimit($row2['historia'], 30);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa contendo condicionais para evitar erro no terceiro parâmetro da função `mb_strpos()`.

Desse modo não precisa se preocupar com a quantidade de caracteres da string original

```
/**
O limite de caracteres.
*/
$limit = 10;

/**
A string original
*/
$str = 'lorem ipsum lorem1 ipsum1';

/**
Obtém a quantidade de caracters da string original
*/
$str_l = mb_strlen($str);

/**
Verifica se o limite é menor que a quantidade de caracters.
Caso o limite seja maior, a função mb_strpos() retornará erro de OffSet, por isso, essa verificação é necessária.
*/
echo (($limit < $str_l)? substr($str, 0, mb_strpos($str, ' ', $limit)).'...' : $str);
```

O problema dessa técnica ou quaisquer outras que utilizam o caracter de espaço é  não ser válida em idiomas que não possuem o caracter de espaço. Portanto, não é uma solução internacionalizada.