# Cortar texto e adicionar reticências

Tags: php

Preciso de uma função que corte um texto sem cortar palavras, adicionando um "..." no final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php

function text_limiter_caracter($str, $limit, $suffix = '...')
{

    while (substr($str, $limit, 1) != ' ') {
        $limit--;
    }

    if (strlen($str) <= $limit) {
        return $str;
    }

    return substr($str, 0, $limit + 1) . $suffix;

}

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 30, '...') . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 60, '...') . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 40, '...') . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 80, '...') . '<br>';
```

Resultado:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor ...
```

Outro solução:

```
function text_limiter_caracter($str, $limit, $suffix = '...')
{

    if (strlen($str) <= $limit) return $str;
    $limit = strpos($str, ' ', $limit);
    return substr($str, 0, $limit + 1) . $suffix;

}

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
$str2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 60) . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 40) . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 80) . '<br>';
echo text_limiter_caracter($str2, 100) . '<br>';
```

Resultado:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Answer (score 6):

Segue uma possibilidade em PHP, baseada [em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13176/70):

```
$tamanho = 300;
$pos = strrpos( $texto.' ', ' ', $tamanho );
$retorno = substr( $texto, 0, $pos - 1 );
if ( $pos < strlen( $texto ) ) $retorno .= '...';
```

Caso vá utilizar textos em UTF-8 dê preferências às funções *multibyte* `mb_strlen` e `mb_strrpos`

Comment: Um problema nisso é que se o texto original for menor que o valor especificado no terceiro argumento da função `strpos()`, retornará erro `strpos(): Offset not contained in string`. Por isso, é mais seguro uma condicional para verificar o tamanho original e comparar com o tamanho de caracteres para o "corte".

Comment: @DanielOmine acho que você não reparou no `$texto.' '`. Sempre vai ter um espaço a ser achado;

Comment: entendi! boa técnica, mas ainda desnecessário pois invoca duas funções para executar algo que talvez nem seja necessário nos casos onde o tamanho da original for menor ou igual ao corte.

Comment: Se eu não fizer a concatenação, que é "barata" até neste contexto, teria que adicionar uma complexidade maior com `if`, além de bagunçar a clareza do código, então no fim acho que acaba compensando. De qualquer forma, observações são sembre bem-vindas para esclarecermos os detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa contendo condicionais para evitar erro no terceiro parâmetro da função `mb_strpos()`.

Desse modo não precisa se preocupar com a quantidade de caracteres da string original

```
/**
O limite de caracteres.
*/
$limit = 10;

/**
A string original
*/
$str = 'lorem ipsum lorem1 ipsum1';

/**
Obtém a quantidade de caracters da string original
*/
$str_l = mb_strlen($str);

/**
Verifica se o limite é menor que a quantidade de caracters.
Caso o limite seja maior, a função mb_strpos() retornará erro de OffSet, por isso, essa verificação é necessária.
*/
echo (($limit < $str_l)? substr($str, 0, mb_strpos($str, ' ', $limit)).'...' : $str);
```

O problema dessa técnica ou quaisquer outras que utilizam o caracter de espaço é  não ser válida em idiomas que não possuem o caracter de espaço. Portanto, não é uma solução internacionalizada.

Postei essa resposta em outra pergunta também, pois acredito que a pergunta aqui pode ser considerada duplicada:

[Como exibir parte de um texto armazenado em uma coluna TEXT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13152/como-exibir-parte-de-um-texto-armazenado-em-uma-coluna-text/97001#97001)

**Solução com CSS**

Uma solução que não necessita de PHP, utiliza os recursos do CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.foo{
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:150px;
    max-height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
</style>

<div class="foo">dsfd fds dgdfg fdg fdgfdg fdg fd1132 errfgdfgf dgf6576576</div>
```